# Inference rules for equality

Tags: logic

Suppose we need to prove a formula $Q$ of the form

$x=y \rightarrow P(x,y)$.

Obviously, the formula $Q$ follows from the formula $P(x,x)$.

That is, there is an inference rule of the form:

from $P(x,x)$ infer $x=y \rightarrow P(x,y)$.

Does this inference rule have a name?

Please also give references where this (or similar) inference rule was described.

Answer (score 2):

By Leibniz's Law
$$P(x,x), x = y \vdash P(x, y).$$
And now applying Conditional Proof, a.k.a. $\to$-introduction, to that we indeed get
$$P(x,x) \vdash x = y \to P(x, y).$$

So the inference rule described in the question is warranted by as a derived rule by Leibniz's Law and Conditional Proof.

Some short-cut rules that are naturally thought of as rules similarly derived from more fundamental rules are used often enough to deserve their own names. But this isn't one of them.